# Correctly folding ASCII characters in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, text-analysis

I'm looking into supporting folding of non standard ASCII characters like [this guide](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/1.x/asciifolding-token-filter.html) suggests.

```
PUT /my_index
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "folding": {
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter":  [ "lowercase", "asciifolding" ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Strangely enough, I'm not able to replicate the sample in the first snippet of code.

When I execute

```
GET /my_index/_analyze?analyzer=folding&text=My œsophagus caused a débâcle
```

the following tokens are returned:

```
sophagus, caused, a, d, b, cle
```

What I want to achieve is:

Variations of the spelling of words like "école" (e.g. ecole, ècole) should be treated as the same word.

Right now, if I execute

```
GET /my_index/_analyze?analyzer=folding&text=école ecole
```

I get the tokens `cole, ecole`

These are the settings I currently use for the text analysis of the documents

```
    "analysis": {
  "filter": {
    "french_stop": {
      "type": "stop",
        "stopwords": "_french_"
    },
      "french_elision": {
        "type": "elision",
          "articles": [
            "l",
            "m",
            "t",
            "qu",
            "n",
            "s",
            "j",
            "d",
            "c",
            "jusqu",
            "quoiqu",
            "lorsqu",
            "puisqu"
          ]
      },
        "french_stemmer": {
          "type": "stemmer",
            "language": "light_french"
        }
  },
    "analyzer": {
      "index_French": {
        "filter": [
          "french_elision",
          "lowercase",
          "french_stop",
          "french_stemmer"
        ],
          "char_filter": [
            "html_strip"
          ],
            "type": "custom",
              "tokenizer": "standard"
      },
        "sort_analyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
            "filter": [
              "lowercase"
            ],
              "tokenizer": "keyword"
        }
    }
}
```

My idea was to change the filters of the index_French analyzer so that the list is the following:

```
"filter": ["french_elision","lowercase","asciifolding","french_stop","french_stemmer"]
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You clearly need to use the `asciifolding` token filter, try it out and you'll see.

Comment: If you refer to the bigger analyzer, you are correct. but I can't get the proper folding using the small sample from the documentation page I linked.

Comment: I just tried and it works fine. Can you try this instead? `curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/my_index/_analyze?analyzer=folding&pretty' -d 'My œsophagus caused a débâcle'`

Comment: Ok strange thing here: if I run in Sense, i get the same issue. If I use Powershell, I get `my, oesophagus, caused, a, debacle`... I missed to specify that the cluster is a Amazon Elasticsearch Service domain.

command: `(iwr -Uri "http://xxxxxxx/my_index/_analyze?analyzer=folding&pretty&text=My œsophagus caused a débâcle").Content`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Sense you need to call the _analyze endpoint like this and it will work:

```
POST /foldings/_analyze
{
   "text": "My œsophagus caused a débâcle",
   "analyzer": "folding"
}
```

You'll get

```
{
   "tokens": [
      {
         "token": "my",
         "start_offset": 0,
         "end_offset": 2,
         "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
         "position": 0
      },
      {
         "token": "oesophagus",
         "start_offset": 3,
         "end_offset": 12,
         "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
         "position": 1
      },
      {
         "token": "caused",
         "start_offset": 13,
         "end_offset": 19,
         "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
         "position": 2
      },
      {
         "token": "a",
         "start_offset": 20,
         "end_offset": 21,
         "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
         "position": 3
      },
      {
         "token": "debacle",
         "start_offset": 22,
         "end_offset": 29,
         "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
         "position": 4
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Ok, I feel stupid now. I got a strange response: it includes "analyzer", "folding" and "text" in the tokens list. http://pastebin.com/6qHDZhK5

Comment: Ok I think you're testing against ES 1.x and I was testing with ES 2.x and `POST _analyze` is only supported in ES 2.x onwards, but try with curl and it will work on both

Comment: Yes. AWS runs on 1.5... iwr on Powershell worked correctly. Is there a reason for the difference?

Comment: probably because of the way how Sense sends/encodes the query

Comment: Glad we figured it out!